# Mocking Stripe in angular karma tests

Tags: javascript, angularjs, unit-testing, karma-runner, stripe-payments

I am having issues mocking the Stripe object for Karma tests. It must be the first script loaded (before angular-stripe).

I am loading this in a script in my karma config:

```
var stripe = new function() {        
    this.setPublishableKey = function(key) {}                
}

Object.defineProperty(window, 'Stripe', { value:  stripe, configurable: true, enumerable: true, writable: true });
```

This gives `Attempting to configurable attribute of unconfigurable property`

I have tried the prototype method but it doesn't recognize any methods I add this way.

```
window.Stripe = function();
window.Stripe.prototype.setPublishableKey = function() {}
```

This gives: `undefined is not a constructor (evaluating 'stripeProvider.setPublishableKey(config.stripeId)')` which I believe I have traced to the method not existing (when I dump window.Stripe in angular-stripe it doesnt show the method)

Finally as an object:

```
window.Stripe = { 
 ...
```

Yields: `Stripe must be available as window.Stripe`. It looks like angular-stripe specifically wants a function.

Whatever Stripe does works if I copy the [stripe](https://js.stripe.com/v2/) file locally - I get other errors about not being on stripe.com so I would like to mock it.

**Solution** Thanks to @estus I was able to solve this the angular way with:

```
angular.module('angular-stripe', []).provider('stripe', {
  setPublishableKey: function() { },
  $get: function() {}   
})
beforeEach(module('app'));
```

The above is enough to override the real loaded `angular-stripe` without throwing Stripe missing errors.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

angular-stripe is an [ultrathin wrapper around `Stripe` global](https://github.com/bendrucker/angular-stripe/blob/master/src/index.js). One of the main benefits of Angular DI is testability.

Mock angular-stripe units instead of Stripe itself, they are there exactly for this.

```
module('app', ($provide) => {
  $provide.provider('stripe', function () {
    this.setPublishableKey = jasmine.createSpy();
    this.$get = jasmine.createSpy();
  });
});
```

Comment: Not sure I understand. If I do not include the angular-stripe file then I need to mock the angular-stripe module which my code loads in the app.js. How will this take care of this?

Comment: I've posted a question directly about this here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37094761/how-to-mock-a-module-in-angular

Comment: angular-stripe is tiny and consists of `Stripe` service (which can be overriden to mock Stripe) and `stripe` service, which uses `Stripe` service. You are free to substitute angular-stripe module fully or partially. To do what you do with Stripe global `module('app', 'angular-stripe', ($provide) => { $provide.constant('Stripe', MockedStripe) })` may be enough.