# How to mock a module in angular

Tags: angularjs, unit-testing

So I've read many posts but no suggestions as worked so far.

I am wanting to mock a module - say angular-foo. The original file is loaded along with everything else.

```
angular.module('app', ['angular-foo'...
```

I would like to mock this module in my karma/mocha tests. I've tried suggestions such as calling it like this but it's a no go.

```
beforeEach(module('app'));

beforeEach(module('angular-foo'))
```

How can I completely prevent the original angular-foo from running (yet it must load as part of the rest of the code)?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

To mock `factory`, `service` and `value` services, [`angular.mock.module` object argument](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngMock/function/angular.mock.module#api-section) can be used

```
beforeEach(module('app', 'angular-foo', {
  fooFactoryService: ...,
  fooValueService: ...
}));
```

To mock the services that are available for injection during config phase (`constant` and `provider`), config function should be used

```
beforeEach(module('app', 'angular-foo', ($provide) => {
  $provide.constant('fooConstantService', ...),
  $provide.provider('fooProviderService', ...),
}));
```

The last module in the row overrides the services from the other ones. The services can be mocked partially (with `$provide.decorator`) or entirely.

If `angular-foo` module isn't loaded at all but other modules make use of it, it can be fully redefined in specs with its mocked version with

```
angular.module('angular-foo', [])...
beforeEach(module('app', 'angular-foo'));
```

Comment: Thanks that got me on the right track:  
`angular.module('angular-stripe', ]).provider('stripe', {  setPublishableKey: function() { },  $get: function() {}  });  beforeEach(module('app'));`

Answer (score 1):

What did the trick for me was putting the provider before the module declaration:

```
  beforeEach(module(function($provide) {
    $provide.provider('myProvider', function() {
      return {
        myProviderFunction: function() {},

        $get: function () {
          return {
            myProviderFunction: function() {}
          };
        }
      };
    });
  }));

  beforeEach(module('myApp'));
```