# How to test angular service with dependencies using jasmine?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, unit-testing, mocking, jasmine

I have service that looks like that:

```
angular.module('app').service('MyService' , function (dependency1, dependency2, dependency3 ...) {
    function funcToTest() {
        // Do something
    }
}
```

How could I inject a specific dependency to the service? For example, I want to inject only `dependency2` to my service and I don't care about the other dependencies.

Comment: Then mock other dependencies. See http://stackoverflow.com/a/37095018/3731501 Actually, in unit test everything but MyService should be mocked.

Comment: Ok but how I actually inject this mocks to the service? @estus

Comment: In no way. You define mocked services in `module`. They are injected automatically.

Comment: @Sagie I have updated my answer to use `$provide` since I misunderstood earlier. apologies!

Answer (score 2):

Unlike unit-testing Angular controllers, we have no way of directly passing dependencies. This is where [**`$provide`**](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/auto/service/$provide) service comes to rescue!

Here's a sample example:

```
beforeEach(module('myApp', function ($provide) {

    mockDependecy2 = {
        mockFunction: function() {}
    };

    $provide.value('dependency2', mockDependecy2);
}));
```

Then, you can write your specs normally:

```
beforeEach(inject(function(_MyService_, ...) {
    ...
    MyService = _MyService_;
}));

describe("...", function() {
    it("...", function() {
        MyService.funcToTest();
        // write expect statements here
    })
})
```

As seen in the example, you can (optionally) enclose them with underscores which are ignored by the injector when the reference name is resolved.

Answer (score 0):

This will automatically inject dependency2 in your service wherever it is used

```
var dependency2;

beforeEach(function () {
    inject(function (dependency2){
        dependency2 = dependency2;
    });
}
```